# What's wrong with my code? Finding element error in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm tring to get output on this to print the append list till 42 element

code:

```py
my_list = []
while True:
    item = input("Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): ")
    if item == 'q':
        break
    my_list.append(item)
    
for item in my_list[:my_list.index(42)]:
    print(item)
```

output:

```
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 1
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 2
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 42
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 4
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    for item in my_list[:my_list.index(42)]:
ValueError: 42 is not in list
```

it's working on given list

code:

```py
my_list = [1,2,3,42,4]

for item in my_list[:my_list.index(42)]:
    print(item)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

I tried using if statement to find 42 but no luck , Thank you in advance for helping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

When you ask an `input` to a user, the result returned by Python is a string so `42` doesn't exist in the list but `'42'`. You have to cast the input as int:

```
my_list.append(int(item))
```

Output:

```
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 1
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 2
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 42
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): 4
Enter an item (or 'q' to quit): q
1
2
```

Note: `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 42, 4]` is not equivalent to `my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '42', '4']`

Obviously, you have to check the user input before:

```
# Method 1: Exception
try:
    my_list.append(int(item))
except ValueError:
    print('Input must be a number')

# Method 2: If/Else
if item.isdigit():
    my_list.append(int(item))
else:
    print('Input must be a number')
```